# Does a 2017 15" Macbook Pro top case fit on a 2016 Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

The keyboard on the 2016 MacBook Pro is very prone to breaking, I've had the top case replaced twice in the past year so far and and I'm for a third time before warranty expires. Does the new 2017 top case fit on a 2016 Macbook Pro? I heard they fixed the keys in the latest iteration.

Best case they will cover it under warranty and switch to the new top case, worst case I'm considering buying a 2017 top case myself and changing.

Comment: Do you mean 2016 MacBook (as in the text) or 2016 MacBook Pro (as in the headlines? Both exist, but they are different machines.

Comment: It's the 2016 rMBP and the 2017 rMBP I'm talking about.

Comment: OK, I have edited your question to refer to the machine you want it to refer to. There's no such thing as a 2016 Retina MacBook Pro either, since Apple have stopped making non-Retina machines and so don't refer to the 2016 MacBook Pros as Retina.

Comment: Seems some users are getting 2017 topcase (or redesigned one): "Apple just replaced my 2016 defective keyboard (top case) with what looks like a 2017 top case (identified by different symbols on option+command). This seems unusual, IMO. o_O"" - https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2016-macbook-pro-issue-high-pitched-keyboard-clicking-sound.2022399/page-57#post-25077943

Comment: After several discussions with Apple support I'm not only getting a 2017 top case, but also a 2017 laptop. Keeping my fingers crossed that it will finally help fix the endless keyboard issues.

Answer (score 2):

No - the parts, keys, electronics and case cables are different.

I'd consider selling the 2016 and buying new if that's the way you want to go.

Comment: Puts me in a bit of a bind, seeing how the unit is defective. Even if they fix the keyboard, it will break sooner rather than later. How can I do that with a straight face? I spent 3500 USD on something and I can't even get it fixed within the warranty period... unbelievable.

Comment: My display had dead pixels once, then my keys broke (got stuck because of debris getting in under the keys, breaking the keyboard itself, which the staff weren't able to fix just by replacing the keys) twice, prompting a replacement of the entire top case in both cases. Edit: Now a couple of my keys are broken once more, and I have a couple more dead pixels on my new display...

Comment: Ugh - makes sense why you’re looking for other avenues.